# Insertar registros nuevos

Tags: r

Tengo estos datos

```
structure(list(col1=c("Grupo1","Grupo1","Grupo1","Grupo1",
"Grupo1","Grupo1","Grupo1","Grupo1","Grupo1","Grupo1","Grupo2",
"Grupo2","Grupo2","Grupo2","Grupo2","Grupo2","Grupo2","Grupo2",
"Grupo2","Grupo2","Grupo2","Grupo2"),col2=c("H","H","H",
"H","M","M","M","M","M","M","H","H","H","H","H","H",
"M","M","M","M","M","M"),col3=c(-3,-2,-1,0,-3,-2,
-1,0,1,2,-3,-2,-1,0,1,3,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1),col4=c("Mal_3",
"Mal_2","Mal_1","Bien","Mal_3","Mal_2","Mal_1","Bien",
"Bien","Bien","Mal_3","Mal_2","Mal_1","Bien","Bien","Bien",
"Mal_4","Mal_3","Mal_2","Mal_1","Bien","Bien"),col5=c(15,
16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,
32,33,34,35,36)),class=c("tbl_df","tbl","data.frame"
),row.names=c(NA,-22L))
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si agrupo por col1 y col2 veo que la col3 va desde -3 a 0 en hombres pero desde -3 a 2 en mujeres.

Quiero insertar los registros que faltan para que la col3 de hombres sea igual a la de mujeres.

De forma que habría que meter en el df las filas en color rosa como nuevos registros.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se podría meter a mano, pero busco alguna forma "automática".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma rápida es usando `expand()`:

```
library(tidyverse)

datos %>%  
  group_by(col1) %>% 
  expand(col2, col3) %>% 
  left_join(datos,
            by = c("col1", "col2", "col3")
  )

# A tibble: 26 x 5
# Groups:   col1 [2]
   col1   col2   col3 col4   col5
   <chr>  <chr> <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
 1 Grupo1 H        -3 Mal_3    15
 2 Grupo1 H        -2 Mal_2    16
 3 Grupo1 H        -1 Mal_1    17
 4 Grupo1 H         0 Bien     18
 5 Grupo1 H         1 NA       NA
 6 Grupo1 H         2 NA       NA
 7 Grupo1 M        -3 Mal_3    19
 8 Grupo1 M        -2 Mal_2    20
 9 Grupo1 M        -1 Mal_1    21
10 Grupo1 M         0 Bien     22
# ... with 16 more rows
# i Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Puedes ver que en caso del `Grupo1` y `H` genero filas para los valores 1 y 2 de `col3`. Es importante agrupar primero por `col1` sino, se expandirá la fila extra del `Grupo2`, es decir `col3=4`, que eventualmente también podría ser deseable.
Ahora si además quieres que `col4` replique los valores de la otra parte del grupo,  hay que hacer algunas cosas más:

```
datos %>%  
  group_by(col1) %>% 
  expand(col2, col3) %>% 
  left_join(datos,
            by = c("col1", "col2", "col3")
  ) %>% 
  mutate(join_col2 = case_when(
                        is.na(col4) & col2 == "H" ~ "M",
                        is.na(col4) & col2 == "M" ~ "H",
                        TRUE ~ col2
                    ),
         col5 = if_else(is.na(col5), 0, col5)
  ) %>% 
  left_join(datos,
            by = c("col1", "join_col2" = "col2", "col3"),
            suffix = c("", ".y")
  ) %>% 
  select(col1, col2, col3, col4=col4.y, col5)

 A tibble: 26 x 5
# Groups:   col1 [2]
   col1   col2   col3 col4   col5
   <chr>  <chr> <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
 1 Grupo1 H        -3 Mal_3    15
 2 Grupo1 H        -2 Mal_2    16
 3 Grupo1 H        -1 Mal_1    17
 4 Grupo1 H         0 Bien     18
 5 Grupo1 H         1 Bien      0
 6 Grupo1 H         2 Bien      0
 7 Grupo1 M        -3 Mal_3    19
 8 Grupo1 M        -2 Mal_2    20
 9 Grupo1 M        -1 Mal_1    21
10 Grupo1 M         0 Bien     22
# ... with 16 more rows
# i Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Básicamente luego de "expandir" las filas, hay que determinar por que `col2` necesitamos volver a "joinear", si el origen es `H` habrá que hacerlo por `M` y viceversa